# Mapping to rename a single column label with a function?

Tags: pandas, indexing, rename

What is the required mapping to rename a column label with a string function?

e.g. this works for all columns:

```
df.rename(columns=str.upper)
```

But with

```
df.rename(columns={'Col 2': str.upper})
```

the resulting label is:

```
<method 'upper' of 'str' objects>
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, n)),
                  columns=[f'Col {i}' for i in range(n)])
renamed = df.rename(columns={'Col 2': str.upper})
print(df)
print(renamed)
```

Comment: If you must use function on only one column, use the following code: `renamed = df.rename(columns={'Col 2': str.upper('Col 2')})` or `renamed = df.rename(columns=lambda x: str.upper(x) if x == 'Col 2' else x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility would be to have the list of columns that you want to change and make a dictionary with the item as upper cases. Two possibilities:

```
l = ['Col 2']

L = [x.upper() for x in l]
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(l, L)))
```

or, more elegantly, with a dictionary comprehension (see comment by mozway):

```
l = ['Col 2']
df.rename(columns={k: k.upper() for k in l})
```

Comment: I'd rather use a dictionary comprehension `df.rename(columns={k: k.upper() for k in l})` in this case.

Comment: Yes, it is more elegant. I change it

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a function as dictionary item. This is actually quite logic, since the key is a column name it assumes you already know this name and thus could craft the expected value.

Thus you should use:

```
df.rename(columns={'Col 2': 'COL 2'})
```

If you know the value can be in a list/set of values you could also use a custom function:

```
def renamer(col):
    if col in {'Col 2'}:
        return col.upper()
    return col

df.rename(columns=renamer)
```

Output:

```
   Col 0  Col 1  COL 2  Col 3
0     18     79      5     79
1     70     43     22     47
2     43      0     79     28
3      7     10     97     49
4     97     16     44      9
```